# jBilling: How to create payment programmatically?

Tags: java, payment, billing

How can I create payment in jBilling programmatically from scheduled plugin? The problem is I want to create a payment which is not linked to any invoice, so I try to use

```
applyPayment(PaymentDTOEx payment, Integer invoiceId, Integer executorUserId)
```

with invoiceId=null, but it leads to an error:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Initially I try:

```
IPaymentSessionBean psb = Context.getBean(Context.Name.PAYMENT_SESSION);
psb.applyPayment(new PaymentDTOEx(paymentWS), null, userID);
```

Later I added "userbl.webServicesAuthenticate(user, pass)" before, but result is the same.

I think I missed something important and maybe doing it completely wrong.

Comment: For the downvoters:  Please consider leaving a comment so that the OP knows what is wrong with their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used jBilling before, but after a bit of googling it seems like it uses Spring to manage transactions etc.

From the error you've quoted it looks like you don't have a Hibernate session open. If you were using a web framework (like Spring MVC, for example), the Hibernate session lifecycle is usually managed for you transparently using a servlet filter.

If you're executing a payment from a scheduled service, then you may need to open and close the Hibernate session yourself in your service. There's some documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) that describes how to do this programmatically using Spring.

Also take a look at the [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) annotation. It might be as simple as annotating your scheduled job method with this.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to right direction! Now it looks obvious, but was not clear for me later, as I try to find reason in jBilling, not thinking about Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rcgeorge23!
The problem was there were no active Hibernate session opened. Here is working code:

```
    IPaymentSessionBean psb = Context.getBean(Context.Name.PAYMENT_SESSION);

    //transaction manager is available in jBilling like that:
    PlatformTransactionManager txManager = Context.getBean(Context.Name.TRANSACTION_MANAGER);

    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setName("CreatePaymentTransaction");
    def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED); //not sure which strategy is best in this case 

    TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    String ret;

    try {
        ret =Integer.toString(psb.applyPayment(new PaymentDTOEx(paymentWS), null, userID));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        txManager.rollback(status);
        throw ex;
    }
    txManager.commit(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create plug-in for user.

for example when user will created or added then the default amount should be paid.

for that you have to write a plug-in and it will occure when user will created.